# Loops and operations

Tags: java, operators, while-loop, boolean

I am having a hard time understanding what this ! in this while loop does.  I know it inverts the boolean value, but how does that cause the loop to exit?   If it is false then it truns it to true, and if it is true then it turns it to false?

```
            String userChoice;
            do
            {

                userChoice = select.promptChoice();


            } while ( !select.isValidChoice(action ) );
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In English:

While `select.isValueChoice(action)` returns `false` (`!true`) do `userChoice = select.promptChoice();`

The reason for the `!` is so that loop exits when `isValidChoice` returns `true`.

Comment: Doesn't the fact that it is a boolean already determine that.  So if isValidChoice return false, is isn't valid, and if it returns true it is.  What is the purpose of the NOT?

Comment: The use of `while` implies interrogation of a boolean value, the `while` will only continue while that value is `true`.

Comment: The use of NOT here is to negate the returned `false` value so that `while` can continue until the method returns `true` (`!true` == `false` so `while` will exit).

Comment: Right, so if is isValidChoice were to return true, the ! would turn it to false, causing the loop to never exit, is that correct?

Comment: No, when `true` is returned from isValidChoice it will be negated and will become `false` and the loop WILL EXIT. It will never exit if isValidChoice always returns `false`, because `!false` is `true`.

Comment: I see now, so the reason for the ! is so that it exits on true, instead of looping on true because normally a loop runs while it is true.  But in this case we want it to exit on true so we negate it so it turn to false.

Comment: Reason for the ! is so that loop exits when isValidChoice returns true. Correct.

Answer (score 4):

The loop continues until the `action` is a valid choice.

That said, the code sample does not show any changes to `action`.

Comment: that is being handled by a method, it will return a string to a boolean which will check that the user made a valid choice, which the boolean will then return true of false.

Answer (score 2):

The loop translate to: If the selection is not valid, then ask for user input again.

The loop exits when the selection is valid, which is negation of the condition in the while loop (not of not valid is valid).

Comment: Doesn't the fact that it is a boolean already determine that.  So if isValidChoice return false, is isn't valid, and if it returns true it is.  What is the purpose of the NOT?

Comment: while means that you repeat the action while the condition is true. If you remove the condition, then the loop will exit when the user input is not valid, and continue asking user for input when the user input is valid, which is not correct. You want to prompt the user until the input is valid.

Answer (score 0):

It means "not". In this case it's saying "NOT is valid choice", or in English "is not a valid choice".

The loop in this case will continue to prompt the user until the choice IS valid.

The ! is used to simply say NOT, in your particular case it would be the same as saying `isValidChoice == false`, you should try to think of these things in plain English in order to better understand them.

Having said that, you aren't required to use the ! if it doesn't sound natural. Here's an example of something that sounds natural using the !.

```
bool happy = true;

if(!happy)
{
   cry();
}

else
{
   smile();
}
```

It depends on what works best for your code, if it sounds natural to use ! then use it, otherwise don't.

EDIT: In either case the loop will break if the result is `FALSE`. The ! is not changing the value of your boolean directly.

Comment: I think I understand now because of your sample.  So basically it is not changing the boolean value, it is asking if what was return is false?

Comment: No it is not really changing the boolean it is checking for it's opposite. But this all depends how you word your boolean variables. If you say !isDead that means it's alive. I usually word my booleans with positive meanings, I would say !isAlive to mean it's dead. But that's just my opinion and may vary depending on your requirements.